# Die richtigen Übersetzungen von »nice to have« und »must have«

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Im Büroalltag verwenden viele meiner Kollegen Anglizismen. Es stört mich, obwohl ich kein Muttersprachler bin. Da diese englische Begriffe im Büroalltag ganz nützlich sind, brauche ich sie auch (aber im Deutschen).

Ich habe selbstverständlich im Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen, aber die Ergebnisse (*Nice to have = optional. Must have = das Muss oder Must-Have*) waren nicht sehr befriedigend.

Was wäre die besten (und natürlich natürlichsten) Übersetzungen für diese Begriffe?

> 'a must-have' - adj: necessary/obligatory/requisite, n:
> necessity/obligation/requisite
>
> 'a could-have' or 'a nice-to-have' - adj: possible/desirable,
> n: possibility/desire

[Source](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/267404)

Comment: Schade, dass du dem Wörterbuch nicht glaubst: Das *Muss* ist durchaus ein sehr gebräuchlicher Ersatz für ein "Must have", besonders gerne auch zum *absoluten Muss* erhoben. Beim "Nice-to-have" gebe ich dir allerdings recht.

Comment: @tofro ja ja, wie ich in meinen Kommentaren geschrieben habe, ist mein großes Problem nicht mit dem "Must-have" sondern "nice-to-have".

Comment: Bei all dem muss-haben und kann-haben fällt mir zur Ergänzung noch die österreichische Kleinanzeigen-Website **will-haben** ein (www.willhaben.at).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Optional* ist eigentlich sehr gut. Auch der Vorschlag *wünschenswert* finde ich eigentlich sehr gelungen, oder ähnlich: *erwünscht*. Ansonsten wird's schwer, es in einem Wort auszudrücken. Das Englische braucht auch drei dafür: nett-zu-haben.

Ansonsten kann man überlegen, was denn ein Synonym zu *nicht notwendig* ist, jedoch eben nicht suggeriert, dass etwas *gar nicht von Nöten* wäre. Da kommen mir folgende Wörter in den Sinn (Reihenfolge ohne Priorisierung):

- unwesentlich
- zusätzlich
- möglich
- fakultativ
- kontingent
- unverbindlich

Oder man kann es mit Wortkombinationen versuchen ala:

- wenn möglich
- gern gesehen

Bleibt noch zu sagen, dass ein Must-have natürlich eine *Notwendigkeit* ist bzw. *notwendig*, oder auch:

- obligatorisch
- (zwingend) erforderlich
- vorgeschrieben
- verbindlich
- bindend
- unerlässlich

Die Listen sind bei Weitem nicht vollständig. Ich würde jetzt entweder *notwendig* / *optional* (oder *wenn möglich*) verwenden, wenn es umgangssprachliche Ausdrücke sein sollen, oder *fakultativ* / *obligatorisch*, wenn's ein wenig fachsprachlicher klingen soll.

Comment: Ich mag sehr deine Antwort (besonders diese Kombinationen). Kann man im Alltag diese Kombinationen so verwenden? Das ist ein gern-gesehenes Komponent? oder Diese Eigenschaft ist ein "wenn-möglich" für unsere Kunden.

Comment: Ich würde nicht mal "Nice-to-have-Komponente" sagen, sondern "Diese Komponente ist nice-to-have". Aber nein, gerade mit den Wortkombinationen solltest du Sätze bilden wie: "Diese Eigenschaft implementieren wir nur, wenn möglich." Als Adjektive würde ich nur die einwörtigen Wörter nehmen. Diese Eigenschaft ist erforderlich, die andere ist optional.

Comment: Aber ich bin immer noch nicht davon überzeugt, dass *optional* gut passt. Die Definition von *optional* ist "possible but not compulsory; left to personal choice". Hier sagt das Wort nicht, ob es gut oder schlecht ist. Es sagt nur ob es möglich oder unmöglich ist.

Comment: Am besten achtest du darauf, was andere Muttersprachler in gewissen Situationen verwenden. Zum Beispiel würde ich so was sagen wie: "Ein mögliches Feature ist..." und ein andere könnte einwenden: "Nein, das ist unwesentlich." Beides Wörter, die ich oben in die selbe Gruppe geschrieben habe, aber im Kontext haben sie hier eine ganz gravierend unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

Comment: Nice-to-have sagt auch nichts über gut und schlecht aus. Wenn du die Gefahr siehst, dass es als "personal choice" abgetan wird, schlage ich wieder wünschenswert als primäre Antwort vor, aber das klingt auf der anderen Seite auch wieder umständlich: Ein wünschenwertes Feature?! Wtf... Dann doch wieder "möglich", was weniger "personal choice" inne hat.

Comment: Doch. Nice to have sagt mir auf jeden Fall was Positives. Optional ist egal ja oder nein. Es hat keine Gewichtung. Aber Wünschenswert ist eher ja als nein.

Answer (score 3):

Für *»must have«* habe ich zwei Vorschläge:

> - ein Muss
>     *(unverzichtbar, ohne gehts nicht)*
> - ein Knüller / Reißer / Kracher / Knaller
>     *(für ein Ding, das so doll ist, dass man es haben **muss**)*

Für *»nice to have«*:

> - ein Schmankerl (Bayern/Österreich: Leckerbissen)
>     *(macht das Leben besser, ist aber nicht unbedingt notwendig)*

Letzteres passt natürlich nicht in jeden Kontext.

Comment: Ich mag deine Definition für nice-to-have (macht das Leben besser, ist aber nicht unbedingt notwendig) sehr. Das ist exakt, was man mit "nice-to-have" meint. Aber leider (wie du in deiner Antwort geschrieben hast) ist das Wort regional und nicht sehr verständlich für alle.

Comment: Schmankerl versteh ich auch als Westdeutscher. Gefällt mir richtig gut die Idee. Dabei kommen mir noch das i-Tüpfelchen, die Krönung und das Nonplusultra in den Sinn.
Leider gefallen mir die Vorschläge für must-have nicht.

Comment: Abgesehen vom "Muss" finde ich diese Vorschläge alle recht flapsig und würde sie im Beruf nicht verwenden.

Comment: @AdInfinitum 'Schmankerl' ist nicht (mehr) regional. +1 dafür, in meinen Augen die bisher beste Übersetzung von "nice-to-have" hier

Answer (score 1):

must have = notwendig
nice to have = Zusatz-, Neben-, sonstige (like a bonus feature)

Comment: Danke schön für Deine Antwort. Aber ich denke, dass diese Übersetzungen auch nicht befriedigend sind. Zusatz-. Neben-, sonstige klingen mehr neutral, wenn nice-to-have klingt mehr positiv.

Comment: how about "wünschenswert"?

Comment: *Wünschenswert* ist viel besser aber immer noch nicht ganz. Ich verstehe so, dass "wünschenswert" was ich mir wünsche ist aber wenn es um "nice to have" geht, meint man mehr *Vorteil* als Wunsch. Ich meine, etwas kann wünschenswert aber nicht nice-to-have (Eiscreme) sein oder nicht wünschenswert aber nice-to-have (Brokkoli).

Comment: Hast Du ein englisches Synonym, das dir gefällt? Auf der Basis könnte man leichter nach geeigneten Übersetzungen suchen.

Comment: Ich habe meine Frage bearbeitet.

Answer (score 1):

Die Ausdruckweise hängt natürlich stark vom Kontext ab. Sagen wir aber mal, wir hören Programmierern bei der Planung eines neuen Stücks Software zu, und einer von ihnen ist einer, der auf deutsche Sprachkultur wert legt und Anglizismen vermeiden möchte (seltsames Szenario...):

> A: Wir sollten unbedingt noch XYZ einbauen.
>
> B: Na ja, das ist vielleicht ein **nettes Extra**, so eine **Dreingabe** halt, oder von mir aus ein **Sahnehäubchen**, aber notwendig ist es nicht. [= *Nice to have*]
>
> A: Oh nein, das ist absolut ein *must-have*! Nur mit XYZ verkaufen wir das wirklich. Das ist nicht nur ein **Gimmick**! Das ist **Brot und Butter**!
>
> B: Das soll ein **Muss** sein? Eine **conditio sine qua non**? Ein **Kernbestandteil**? Ein **Kernstück**?
>
> A: Ja, wenn du es so ausdrücken willst. Ja. Ich halte das für ein absolutes **Desiderat**, ein **unverzichtbares Element**, ohne das können wir uns das Projekt gleich an den Hut stecken! Ohne das kauft das einfach keiner.
>
> B: Ich weiß nicht ... ich halte das trotzdem für **Mätzchen**, irgendwie **Firlefanz.** Das **fünfte Rad am Wagen** fast. [= unnötig, überflüssig, hinderlich]
>
> A: Im Gegenteil! Nur mit XYZ wird **eine runde Sache** draus! Nur mit XYZ wird ein Schuh draus! [= XYZ ist ein *must-have*]

Ja, ich weiß, Mätzchen, Firlefanz und fünftes Rad am Wagen sind nicht "*nice to have*" sondern eher "*really not necessary*", und Gimmick kommt auch aus dem Englischen. Aber vielleicht hilft es dir ja, ein breiteres Wortfeld zu sehen.

Comment: Ein 'Desiderat' ist nun gerade kein "must have", sondern etwas, was man sich "wünscht", was man gern hätte, also eher "nice to have"

Answer (score 1):

Für "nice to have" gibt es meiner Meinung nach keinen hundertprozentigen deutschen Begriff. Die meisten deutschen Begriffe, die mir einfallen, decken nur einen Teilbereich der Bedeutung ab oder sind zu allgemein. Bei der Erweiterung von "Option" oder "Zusatz" mit passenden Adjektiven erzeugt man auch schnell unbeabsichtigte Tautologien.

Mögliche Ersatzbegriffe sind z.B.:

1. **...ein nettes Extragimmick** - Auch wenn das auch teilweise ein Anglizismus ist, meiner Ansicht nach noch am ehesten an der englischen Bedeutung, leider aber nur umgangssprachlich zu gebrauchen.
2. **...eine Option** - zu "optional", aber möglicherweise mit *wünschenswert* oder *empfehlenswert* etwas näher an die Bedeutung von "nice to have" zu bringen - **...eine verzichtbare, aber empfehlenswerte Option** (was wie oben erwähnt, aber leider in die Nähe einer Tautologie rutscht)
3. **..nicht unbedingt nötig** - bringt leider nicht zum Ausdruck, dass man's trotzdem gerne hätte, dasselbe gilt auch für
4. **...nicht zwingend erforderlich**

Answer (score 0):

Generell: Etwas, das *must have* ist, ist nowendig und etwas, das *nice to have* ist, ist nicht notwendig.

Genauer:

> Must have = notwendig, nötig, unverzichtbar
>
> Nice to have = verzichtbar, entbehrlich

Die Wörter klingen jetzt vielleicht etwas seltsam; ich vermute, dass sich gerade deshalb in vielen Bereichen des Lebens diese Anglizismen heutzutage durchgesetzt haben.

Comment: Danke schön für Deine Antwort. Wie ich in meinem anderen Kommentar für User9 geschrieben habe, ist es vielleicht einfacher eine passende Übersetzung für "Must-have" zu finden. Aber Deine Übersetzungen für"nice-to-have" fassen nicht 100% um. Besonders *verzichtbar* gibt einen negativen Eindruck. z.B *Dieses Modul ist für unsere neue Software verzichtbar* bedeuetet mehr wir sollen dieses Modul loswergen, weil es kein Muss ist.

Comment: Ich gebe dir recht, "verzichtbar" ist leicht negativ konnotiert und deshalb nicht unproblematisch. Jedoch glaube ich, dass meine Übersetzungen der Lösung recht nahe kommen (auch wenn natürlich im Alltag vor allem die Anglizismen gebraucht werden). Als Bsp.: "Ohne meinen Laptop könnte ich nicht leben, jedoch ist das Tablet für mich _Nice-to-have_"; das heisst der Laptop wäre für mich absolut nötig, wohingegen ich das Tablet entbehren könnte, es ist nicht unbedingt nowendig für mich. Bspw. empfinde ich das Wort "unnötig" als viel negativer konnotiert als "entbehrlich" oder sogar "verzichtbar"

Comment: Die Vorschläge für *nice to have* sind m. E. falsch gepolt, sie bringen nur zum Ausdruck, dass die Eigenschaft nicht notwendig ist, nicht aber (wie *nice to have*), dass man sie trotzdem gerne hätte. Meine Vorschläge dafür: *Nützlich*, *wünschenswert*.

Answer (score 0):

Vielleicht:

must-have - notwendig(keit) und

nice-to-have - habenswert(es)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19268)

Comment: I'm not critiquing or requesting clarification, I am exactly answering the question, even if I am not 100% sure that the answer is correct (though I believe it to be - which is different from knowing it to be with certainty).

Comment: Ich denke auch, dass es eine gute Antwort ist. Danke schön :)

Comment: Ein bisschen mehr Erklärung wäre hilfreich, sonst kann man auch direkt ins Wörterbuch gucken. Da gibt es dann auch direkt die korrekte Großscheibung dazu.

Comment: "habenswert" ist meiner Meinung nach die falsche Übersetzung.

Comment: Wieso? Ich konnte die Bedeutung eigentlich nirgendwo online finden aber Google Translate uebersetzt den Satz "Das is habenswert" als "This is desirable".

Comment: Das ist* habenswert...

Comment: @inarilo Ich denke das ist so ein "erfundenes" Wort. In manchen Websites wird dieses Wort benutzt aber keiner dieser Websites hat einen ernsthaften Inhalt.

Comment: Aber ich habe es nicht von Websites gelernt, aber als Kind in Deutschland, und von Gespraechen mit deutschen Bekannten u. vielleicht auch Buecher die ich gelesen habe, Also, ich weiss nicht genau von wo ich es habe aber Websites bestimmt nicht (denn ich benutze ja keine deutsche Websites).